# Long .htaccess RewriteRules

Tags: .htaccess

How do I get

> http://nebulaproject.net/forum/topic/1

to turn into

> http://nebulaproject.net/forum/topic.php?id=1

I thought,

```
RewriteRule ^/forum/topic/(.*) /forum/topic.php?id=$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^/forum/(.*)/(.*) /forum/$1.php?id=$2 [L]
```

might work, but... No luck. I have other `RewriteRules` setup such as `/players/Haribo98` to `/player/index.php?username=Haribo98`